# Как отслеживать url в формах Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Есть сайт на Django для бронирования номеров в разных отелях (13 штук- 13 страниц), данные из заполненной формы записываются в БД. Ничего лучше не придумал как создать 13 одинаковых таблиц с разными названиями для каждого отеля. Но это сильно противоречит принципу DRY. Поэтому вопрос - как можно отследить url с которого передаётся форма и автоматически заполнять ячейку названием отеля в БД.

```
class ReceptionAlexander(models.Model):
date_first = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заезда')
date_second = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выезда')
rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество номеров', default=1)
adult = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество взрослых гостей', default=1)
kids = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество детей', default=0)
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='ФИО', max_length=40)
phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер телефона', max_length=12)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Александр Хаус'

class ReceptionGalunov(models.Model):
date_first = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заезда')
date_second = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выезда')
rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество номеров', default=1)
adult = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество взрослых гостей', default=1)
kids = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество детей', default=0)
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='ФИО', max_length=40)
phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер телефона', max_length=12)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Галунов Отель'

class ReceptionGelvecia(models.Model):
date_first = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заезда')
date_second = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выезда')
rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество номеров', default=1)
adult = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество взрослых гостей', default=1)
kids = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество детей', default=0)
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='ФИО', max_length=40)
phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер телефона', max_length=12)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Отель Гельвеция'
```

Форма

```
class ReceptionFormGelvecia(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ReceptionGelvecia
    fields = ['date_first', 'date_second', 'rooms', 'adult', 'kids', 'name', 'phone']
```

И так далее к каждой таблице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно пересмотреть архитектуру ваших модейлей. Создайте две зависимые таблицы.

Создаёте модель Hotel в которой у Вас будет хранится все отели , его название и месторасположение (для примера).

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

После чего создаёте модель под бронирование.

```
class ReceptionAlexander(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='h_name', blank=False, null=False)
    date_first = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заезда')
    date_second = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выезда')
    rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество номеров', default=1)
    adult = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество взрослых гостей', default=1)
    kids = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество детей', default=0)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='ФИО', max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер телефона', max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' | '.join([self.hotel_name, self.name])
```

И получится следующее, в поле hotel_name у вас будет перечень всех созданных отелей. Через Django Forms создаете выпадающий список для поля hotel_name на основе таблицы Hotel.
По итогу у Вас будет 2 model, 1 forma и 1 url.

Либо создаёте одну модель

```
class ReceptionAlexander(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    date_first = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заезда')
    date_second = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выезда')
    rooms = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество номеров', default=1)
    adult = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество взрослых гостей', default=1)
    kids = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество детей', default=0)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='ФИО', max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер телефона', max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' | '.join([self.hotel_name, self.name])
```

И после чего в django forms создаёте под поле hotel_name  выпадающий список.

```
Hotels =(
    ("1", "Редисон"),
    ("2", "Хаятт"),
    ("3", "Континенталь"),
    ("4", "Четыре сизона"),
)
  
# creating a form 
class HotelForm(forms.Form):
    hotel_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Hotels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('Reception', views.receptions)
]
```